# Including bootstrap.min.css breaks my <input type="range">

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to include a slider in a website form.  The code I have is here:

```
<body>
    <div style="background-color: #F1F1F1">
        <div class="row">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <form action="/Beneficiary/Primary" method="post">
            <label for="fader">Percentage</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="fader" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
            <output for="fader" id="volume">50</output>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

This code works and can be see here: https://codepen.io/jonathn6/pen/qxMxBm

The problem is when I include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

When this stylesheet is included, without making any changes to any HTML, the `<output>` gets placed under the `<input>`.  In addition, the length of the slider expands across the entire page.

Is it possible that there is a default type=range attribute somewhere in the bootstrap.min.css file that forces the type=range element to expand to the maximum width?

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if I used this code in the range type input tag it would solve the second problem:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<input type="range" style="width: <width>" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="fader" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
<!-- ... -->
```

Width: Any css measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the element in a container and give it width. In the application I'm developing, I moved all elements to the `<div>` element with the `customContainer` class style applied. The `customContainer` class style assigns a value of 200px to the width field to set the `width` of the element.

```js
let volume = document.getElementById('volume');

function outputUpdate(value) {
  volume.value = value;
}
```

```css
/* Developed the following class style. */
.customContainer{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <!-- The following item is plugin and customContainer class style is applied -->
  <div class="customContainer">
    <div style="background-color: #F1F1F1">
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <form action="/Beneficiary/Primary" method="post">
            <label for="fader">Percentage</label>
            <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="fader" step="1" oninput="outputUpdate(value)">
            <output for="fader" id="volume">50</output>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```